Calendar Settings in iPhone simulator
I’m working on an iOS app which accesses the calendar.
It woks well enough but I want to change the calendar settings in the iPhone simulator. However the settings app on the simulator doesn’t include anything for the Calendar app. The Calendar app does appear as one of the few install apps.
Is there some way either to get the Calendar app to appear in settings or to access it some other way?

I'm going to say "no"...
There is not documentation on this topic, but its been that way for a while.
Most of my apps integrate with data sources from first party apps (Messages, Contacts, etc.) and you just get used to testing on-device for stuff that seems like it should run in the simulator. Long ago, the simulator was closer to a full iPhone, but I wonder if they started removing things to keep people from using the simulator as an iOS virtual container. [Circa iOS 9 and 10]
(I've had a side calendar project, Xcode 14->present).
